# Tooltip with ::usage information in code blocks

Tags: discussion, site-tools

I made userscript displaying the ::usage message of symbols when hovered in a code block:

[image: Pause example]

---

[The script is available on github](https://github.com/simonschmidt/SE-Usage-Message)

It looks good for the vast majority of symbols but there are some limitations:

- The `title` attribute used for tooltips doesn't allow html, causing some symbols for instance `Integrate` to have "Subscript/Supscript/Subsuperscript" in the description:

[image: Integrate example]

- I couldn't find good replacement for all the Private Use Area unicode symbols, for instance `\[Conjugate]`.
- I have v8 so symbols introduced in v9 will not get a tooltip.

Comment: If you extracted the usage messages programmatically, you may want to make sure that you did not violate the WRI's license agreement. For example, for the IntelliJ IDEA plugin of halirutan, when he needed to do the same, I asked internally and, while the decision was positive, this wasn't completely automatic.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'll send a mail to WRI and see what's what, worst case people will just have to evaluate the included notebook to generate the ::usage stuff for themself

Comment: Let me know how this goes. If things are not good, I will try to help.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, I'll let you know if they respond.

Comment: @ssch Any update on this from WRI?